# Basic RegEx in Stackoverflow

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, plpgsql

Given an input like one of the following, I need to check if it matches given text, of the format 'ABCD1234':

- ABCD1### matches ABCD1943, ABCD1300, but does not match ABCD2042 or FOOB3075
- DCBA[98]### matches DCBA9012, DCBA8899 but not DCBA6211
- ####1### matches ABCD1848 and BARR1093
- (ABCD|FOOB|BARR)2### matches ABCD2999, FOOB2533, BARR2222
- ABCD1234,WXYZ9876 matches only ABCD1234, WXYZ9876
- DCBA9###,DCBA8### matches the same things as DCBA[98]### above

I'm writing this like a function that has the following structure:

```
create or replace function modifiedRegEx(pattern text, tester text) 
RETURNS boolean
AS $re$
DECLARE
    isMatch boolean;
BEGIN
    isMatch := TRUE;
    return isMatch;
END;
$re$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Obviously the above will return `TRUE` every time. I was wondering if anyone could please suggest some string functions that might be helpful in checking the above? I'm at a loss, even after reading the PostgreSQL string functions docs.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to make sure - are You asking for a translator from Your "modifiedRegEx" to a normal regex? I hope "DCBA[98]### matches DCBA4012, DCBA3899" is a typo. I guess if You just replace "###" with "[0-9]*", "####" with "[A-Z]*" and "," with "|" - it'd do what You asked...

Comment: Yep it was a typo. And no, I don't want translation to regular regex, I want the function to return TRUE if the input pattern matches the input tester, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html

This one returns true:

`SELECT 'DCBA9012' similar to 'DCBA[98]___';`

or:

`SELECT 'DCBA9012' ~  'DCBA[98]...';`